# How to set vim as the default Text editor?

Tags: windows, vim, gvim

I'm trying to set gVim to be the default text editor on Windows but it won't work. It works with notepad++, editor... but not with Vim. Any ideas how to fix it?

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/lm069a

I also tried to choose gvim.exe with the option that opens the explorer. if I open it it works, but it doesn't save Vim as the default text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing piece is probably adding Gvim to your PATH variable.

Once you have done that, verify it by starting a Command Prompt (cmd)
and trying the command `gvim`.

You may then add it as default editor by right-click on a `.txt` file,
select *Open With > Choose Program*, and choose
"Vi improved - A Text Editor".
If the entry is not already there, browse for `gvim.exe`.
Don't forget to tick "Always use the selected program ..." before clicking OK.

Comment: user variable or system variable?

Comment: User if you only use it under your login, system for all users.

Comment: ive made a user path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81) but it still doesnt work

Comment: Doesn't work how?